# Compare adjacent elements and replace

Tags: python, r

I have a tab-delimited input file like this,

```
mar1 A B A A
mar2 A B A A
mar3 B U A A
mar4 A B A A
mar5 A B A A
```

I would like to convert all singletons in the neighbouring markers,like this

```
mar1 A B A A
mar2 A B A A
mar3 A B A A
mar4 A B A A
mar5 A B A A
```

How to do this in R? python is ok as well.

Comment: Does neighboring only mean previous and next row? or do you want to replace value with mode? What to do with first and last row?

Comment: yep, previous and next, I don't care about the 1st and last row at the moment, as I want to simplify the algorithm for now...

Comment: Later, I would like to use the sliding window, but to start neighbouring SNPs are fine for me